# JS - запись/захват системного звука

Tags: javascript, html5, webrtc

Современные браузеры позволяют давать доступ, и соответственно вести запись:

1. С веб камеры пользователя.
2. С микрофона пользователя.
3. С экрана пользователя.
4. Так-же все эти каналы информации можно транслировать между пользователями через WebRTC (без участия сервера).

Последний кирпичик, о котором не могу найти информацию: запись системного звука (того, что пользователь слышит в колонках). Возможно ли это сегодня? Если да - то был бы очень благодарен за пример, или ссылку на статью.

Comment: кажется, сейчас это нельзя осуществить